# Creating a SSH connection in a program?

Tags: c, ssh

I am writing a programing (in C) in which I have to access data from another computer through an SSH connection. I was wondering how to create the SSH connection within the program.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One easy solution would be to use the `ssh` binary and call that from your program. Create 3 pipes using `pipe()`, then `fork()`, `close()` the appropriate endpoints (not sure if that's needed) so you have 2 processes with 3 pipes between them. On the child, `dup2()` the pipe endpoints to stdin, stdout and stderr (i.e. fd's 0, 1, 2) and `exec()` the ssh command.

On the parent process you can now just talk to the other side. Use RSA authentication to get rid of password stuff.

But there may be libraries to just connect, I don't know ;-)

Comment: lol ;-) as much as I like this, I don't think it should be the top answer.

Comment: You don't strictly *need* to `close` the appropriate endpoints, but you can't read from a write end and certain children won't need access to certain endpoints, so there's no reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/). Have you attempted to look for an answer yourself? Have you tried using some libraries and haven't got them working?

It is always best to try to help yourself before looking for handouts. YMMV.

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow are handouts? That was a little harsh.

Comment: When no prior attempt at finding the information that is widely (and easily) found, yes. Same as when you are at work or anywhere else in real life, at least make an attempt to find the information before asking for someone else to give it to you (aka, asking for a handout).

Comment: So you picked libssh because of the name?